# How would I show a drop down in asp.net mvc for a virtual list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a list thats being generated in my objects like so

```
public virtual List<Person> TargetAudience { get; set; }
```

How would I go about adding a drop down list off this into my view?  I've used

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TargetAudience, 
new SelectList(Model.TargetAudience.Select(x => 
new { Value = x.Id, Text = x }), "Value", "Text"))
```

and that just tells me the object reference is not an instance of an object.

UPDATE:

I've added the line to look like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedTargetAudience, new SelectList(Model.TargetAudience, "ID", "DisplayName"))
```

my model now has this:

```
public virtual List<Person> TargetAudience { get; set; }
    public int SelectedTargetAudience { get; set; }
```

the DisplayName comes from the person reference

```
public string DisplayName { get { return Firstname + " " + Lastname; } }
```

Comment: The `SelectList` should be `new SelectList(Model.TargetAudience, "ID", "DisplayProperty")` where "DisplayProperty" is the name of a property in `Person`, but this should be set in the controller, not the view, and you need a property to bind to (for example `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTargetAudience, ..`) where `SelectedTargetAudience` is typeof `int` assuming `Person.ID` is typeof `int`.

Comment: Updated per your instructions. I still get the same error. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Have you initialized `TargetAudience` (is it `null`)? Does it contain `Person` objects? And as you have `public virtual List<Person> TargetAudience { get; set; }` are you wanting to select only one or multiple `Person`'s?

Comment: I confused by your `virtual List<Person>` property. Is this generated by EF? If so I think you might be misunderstanding the purpose of `DropDownListFor` It should be rendering a collection of **all** `Person`'s from the database, so you can select one (or use `ListBoxFor` if you want to select one or more)